# Webkit Cocoa - WebView issues

Tags: cocoa, webkit

Within a Cocoa application I have a webview. When Google's personalized home page loads I get the following message caught by the WebViewDelegate:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.google.ca/ from frame with URL http://www.ig.gmodules.com/gadgets...
```

Is there a setting that I set to make this error go away? It doesn't seem to cause any actual problems, but should be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like an issue on Google's end, I don't think there's anything you can do there. It means that an iframe with www.ig.gmodules.com loaded is trying to request something from www.google.ca, which according to the browser is a cross-domain request. If Google wanted to allow that they'd need a crossdomain.xml allowing the requests.

Comment: Indeed, I used chrome and got the same error - Should have done that first!